# SQL Query - Select a value, then use it again in following statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried looking it up, and while I think this should be possible I can't seem to find the answer I need anywhere.

I need to lookup a date from one table, then store it for use in a following query.
Below is statements that should work, with my setting the variable (which I know won't work, but I'm unsure the best way to do/show it otherwise - bar maybe querying it twice inside the if statement.)

I'm then wanting to in the latter statement, use either the date given in the second query, or if the date from the first query (that I'm thinking to set as a variable) is newer, use that instead.

```
startDateVariable = (SELECT `userID`, `startDate`
FROM `empDetails`
WHERE `userID` = 1);
                                                 
SELECT `userID`, SUM(`weeksGROSS`) AS yearGROSS 
FROM `PAYSLIP`
WHERE `date` <= "2021-11-15"
AND `date` >= IF( "2020-11-15" > startDateVariable , "2020-11-15" , startDateVariable )
AND `userID` IN ( 1 )
GROUP BY `userID`
```

*Naturally all dates given in the query ("2021-11-15" etc) would be inserted dynamically in the prepared statement.*

Now while I've set the `userID` IN to just query 1, it'd be ideal if I can lookup multiple users this way at once, though I can accept that I may need to make an individual query per user doing it this way.

Much appreciated!

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: you can join the two tables and your `IF`  will be based from the `empdetails`

Comment: SQL version "10.3.32-MariaDB"

Comment: I haven't needed to merge tables before, but now that you mention it, it makes sense, I'll contemplate that and see what i can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns I was going about this the wrong way, looks like the best way to do this or something similar is by using **SQL JOIN**
This allows you to query the tables as if they are one.
I also realised rather then using an IF, i could simply make sure i was looking up newer or equal to both the date given and the start date.

Below is working as required. And allows lookup of multiple users at once as wanted.

```
SELECT PAYSLIP.userID, employeeDetails.startDate, SUM(PAYSLIP.weeksGROSS) AS yearGROSS 
FROM PAYSLIP
INNER JOIN employeeDetails ON employeeDetails.userID=PAYSLIP.userID
WHERE PAYSLIP.date <= "2021-11-15"
AND PAYSLIP.date >= "2020-11-15"
AND PAYSLIP.date >= employeeDetails.startDate
AND PAYSLIP.userID IN ( 1,2,8 )
GROUP BY PAYSLIP.userID
```

See here for more usage examples: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

However along the lines of my particular question, it's possible to store variables. I.E.
`SET @myvar= 'Example showing how to declare variable';`
Then use it in the SQL statement by using
`@myvar` where you want the variable to go.